# cassandra: variable number of column in single row

Tags: sql, database, cassandra

i want to design column family to store chatting history for couple of clients ,
 storing all the history for one particular couple in one row,
 for a given row,how  we store only the columns required for that row.

Sample:

```
id1 | id2 | message1 | message2
5     2     "hey"      "why"
id1| id2  | message1 | message2 | message3 | message4
2     3     "dcx"       "ddfs"    "ddd"         "dd"

id1| id2  | message1 | message2 | message3 | message4
4     6     "dcx"       "ppp"    

create columnfamily chat (id1 int,id2 int primary key)
insert into chat(id1,id2) values(8103333,8104444);
```

i want to add new columns `'message1'`,`'message2'` ......etc in the same row 
so how i can create columns in a particular row 
iam useing cqlsh 2.3.0 | cassandra 1.2.1 | cql space 3.0.0

Answer (score 5):

Instead of message1, message2, etc. columns, use a compound key like this:

```
CREATE TABLE chat (
   id1 int,
   id2 int,
   message_sent_at timestamp,
   message text,
   primary key ((id1, id2), message_sent_at)
)
```

Cassandra will now cluster messages belonging to the id1/id2 pair in chronological order for you.

See http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1 and http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/ddl/table#cassandra-tables.

Comment: thanks so much , but i want to store all message in one row, because i think that the horizontal search faster than the vertical. if this wrong idea how i can insert the timestamp formate